# how to convert int64-fixed-point to double?

Tags: c++

I'm using `int64` to store my `decimal` values. In financical I need "exact" values so I have to use `base 10` not `base 2`. I have this globally:

```
typedef int64_t myDecimal;
const int DECIMALS_GLOBAL = 10;
```

I "multiple" each value to `10^10`
For example

```
1 is 10000000000
0.001 is 10000000
```

Now I need to convert `myDecimal` to `double`. It sounds simple I just can `((double) myDecValue) / 10^10` but this is risky because it's pretty likely that `double` is not capable to store "big" int64 values. So I wrote such function:

```
int64_t posPow10_64[] = {
1,
10,
100,
1000,
10000,
100000,
1000000,
10000000,
100000000,
1000000000,
10000000000,
100000000000,
1000000000000,
10000000000000,
100000000000000,
1000000000000000
};

double Utils::MyDecimalToDouble(myDecimal value) {
    int beforeDot = value / posPow10_64[DECIMALS_GLOBAL];
    return (double) beforeDot + ((double) (value - beforeDot * posPow10_64[DECIMALS_GLOBAL])) / posPow10_64[DECIMALS_GLOBAL];
}
```

I think this function is less risky because I cast to double signifficantly smaller value, but this function looks very complicated and likely slow.

What would you recommend, is my problem common, how to convert to double fast simple and safe?

Comment: that appears to be a very, very bad design....

Comment: @MitchWheat why? what would you recommend for `decimal` in c++?

Comment: Do your SAN stat a favour and use an established bignum library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: Either use bigdecimal, or store whole cents.

Comment: It's already proven that you *can't* exactly represent every value you want in a double, no gymnastics you do are going to change that. They'll just redistribute the rounding errors (generally for the worse).

Comment: Boost also has what seems to be a [C++ wrapper for GMP](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html).

Comment: i need exact values in base 10! this means i need exactly 10.01, but not 10.009999999! how fast GMP is? because basic operations with `int64` are very fast.

Comment: @javapowered unless, of course, you provide additional information stating that not every 64-bit int is actually a valid value in your fixed-point system. Then, it *may* be possible that conversion to double is accurate, but all you would have to do is divide by the scale.

Comment: @javapowered What would an answer to "how fast" be? It might be **fast enough**, which you can find out by testing. If, however, you need to perform arithmethics on decimal numbers where rounding behaviour is something you can work with, it's probably what you should be using, **without** converting intermediate values or results to `double`. (Unless it's at a boundary where you're willing to accept the loss of precision.)

Comment: double is always "approximation". the question is how to convert to double fast and safe? yes when acceptable I do ariphmentic with `myDecimal` but sometimes I need to convert it to "closest" double value.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can tell you what would be "safe". The calculation "value / 100.0" is not safe in that it introduces rounding errors. Your calculation also isn't safe because calculating the "after dot" part introduces rounding errors, and I believe adding the two together might as well. Which ones do you like better?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding *“it's pretty likely that double is not capable to store "big" int64”*, that depends on whether you mean *exactly*. Since you're doing **decimal fixed point**, most of the values you have can't be stored exactly unless the implementation's `double` type happens to be decimal (which it in principle can be, unlike integers which have to be binary). For example, 0.2 can't be stored exactly with any ordinary `double` type, because it can't be expressed exactly as a sum of powers of 2.

However, if it can't be stored exactly then it can't be stored exactly, and no amount of smart conversion apparatus can work around that.

Typically a `double` is 64-bit IEEE floating point with roughly 52 bits precision, and with range much larger than 64-bit integer, so magnitude is no problem.

---

Summing up, you can just do `double(myDecValue) / 10000000000` (note that `10^10` is a bitlevel xor expression).

Comment: `int64` is in range –9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. do you think I can cast 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 to doulbe not loosing any information ? if (int64) (double) 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 == 9,223,372,036,854,775,807?

Comment: @javapowered: as mentioned you can't even convert 0.2 to `double` without losing information (for an ordinary C++ implementation). apparently you have two mutually exclusive requirements: (1) convert to `double`, and (2) not lose information in any case. you then have to ditch at least one requirement.

Comment: I can loose reasonable number of information. Of course I will loose information when casting to double. But it seems `double` loose a lot. I've tried this `std::cout << (double) 11234567899 / 10000000000 << std::endl;` and output is `1.12346`. So I have ~0.00001 precision. Why? Double is 8 bytes and it can remember only 5 digits after dot even when I have just `1` before dot?

Comment: @javapowered: the output depends on your output settings. set fixed format and precision 16 to 18 digits. this should be covered by your c++ textbook?